# STM32F429 PPS output signal from TIM2

Tags: timer, synchronization, stm32

I'm trying to generate PPS signals for PTP synchronization using stm32f429 microcontroller.

I configured GPIOG 8 pin as AF pin and TIM2 as SLave in trigger mode with ITR1 trig source.

TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef tim_pps;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio_pps;

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOG, ENABLE);

```
// Configure pin PG8 = PTP PPS Out
gpio_pps.GPIO_Pin   = GPIO_Pin_8;
gpio_pps.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
gpio_pps.GPIO_Mode  = GPIO_Mode_AF;
gpio_pps.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
gpio_pps.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &gpio_pps);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_ETH);

TIM_DeInit(TIM2);

TIM_RemapConfig(TIM2, TIM2_ETH_PTP);

TIM_TimeBaseStructInit(&tim_pps);
tim_pps.TIM_Period = 0;
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &tim_pps);

TIM_SelectSlaveMode(TIM2, TIM_SlaveMode_Trigger);
TIM_SelectInputTrigger(TIM2, TIM_TS_ITR1);    

TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
```

But i have no signal on PG8. What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

If you set **TIM_Period = 0** - so your timer won't work.

It is good practice to read datasheets for understand hardware limitations. 
Open reference manual according to your MCU and see description of TIM1_ARR register.

[image: usual TIM_ARR description]